# Switching an input to a slider

Tags: slider, formpage

I have a code that works well. The code has been show below.

I want to switch the input 'k1' from being being a single value input to a slider between 0 and 1 in steps of 0.1. What would be the best way to do that? Would it be the use of 'Manipulate' or would it be some other function?

Thank you!

Sid

```
   CloudDeploy[
 FormPage[{"k1" -> "Number", "n1" -> "Number", "n2" -> "Number"},
  
  (fig1 = 
     SmoothHistogram[
      Table[Table[
        If[RandomReal[] > #k1, RandomChoice[{100, 90}], 
         RandomChoice[{80, 70, 60, 50, 40}]], #n1], #n2], 
      PlotStyle -> Red]; 
    Show[{fig1}]) &
  ]
```

]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Slider` control

```
FormPage[{"k1" -> <|"Interpreter" -> Restricted["Real", {0, 1, .1}], 
    "Control" -> Slider|>, "n1" -> "Number", 
  "n2" -> 
   "Number"}, (fig1 = 
    SmoothHistogram[
     Table[
      Table[
       If[RandomReal[] > #k1, RandomChoice[{100, 90}], 
        RandomChoice[{80, 70, 60, 50, 40}]], #n1], #n2], 
     PlotStyle -> Red];
   Show[{fig1}]) &]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly.

Comment: You are welcome. Would you mind accepting the answer?